# Why Mysql use index for a single table, but not when join

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I wonder why mysql use index for a single table query, while not for a join query, even i force using index.

Just show the tables and querys:

```
show create table dc_assess_plan_batch;
CREATE TABLE `dc_assess_plan_batch` (
   `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `app_batch_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '数据来源的id ',
   `project_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT '课程计划id',
   `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '批次名',
   `time` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '批次的时间',
   `batch_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '1.可用关系.0 不可用',
   `app_from` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '数据来源',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `inx_project_id` (`project_id`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `app_batch_id` (`app_batch_id`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

```
CREATE TABLE `dc_assess_task` (
   `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '任务名称',
   `class_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '班级id',
   `course_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '课程id',
   `app_from` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '成绩来源',
   `term_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '学期id',
   `publish_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '任务发布时间',
   `completion_degree` double(10,3) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '完成度',
   `course_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '课程名称',
   `school_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `app_batch_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `score_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '''成绩计算规则 COUNT :按数量,  SCORE:按照分数, KCBCOUNT:按课程币数量'',',
   `xxpj_mode` enum('BY_GROUP','BY_PERSON') DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '线下评价评分模式',
   `upload_flag` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '标志任务是否线下上传，1是，0否',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `FKrx8fxs12oe1mafttciiwir6cm` (`app_from`) USING BTREE,
   KEY `app_batch_id` (`app_batch_id`) USING BTREE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**There are two tables, and both have index on filed 'app_batch_id'**

- query1:

```
explain select * from dc_assess_plan_batch where app_batch_id = '2ebb4066038441229e937d2de4a9b5632018-12-07';

# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1   SIMPLE  dc_assess_plan_batch    ref app_batch_id    app_batch_id    767 const   1   Using index condition
```

- query2

```
explain select * from dc_assess_plan_batch dapb join dc_assess_task dat on dapb.app_batch_id = dat.app_batch_id where dat.course_id = '562aecc2d1c64fabbff4a18496acc757';

# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1   SIMPLE  dapb    ALL app_batch_id                277947  
1   SIMPLE  dat ref app_batch_id    app_batch_id    767 ifass.dapb.app_batch_id 1   Using where
```

-query3

```
explain select * from dc_assess_plan_batch dapb force index (app_batch_id) join dc_assess_task dat on dapb.app_batch_id = dat.app_batch_id where dat.course_id = '562aecc2d1c64fabbff4a18496acc757';

# id, select_type, table, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, Extra
1   SIMPLE  dapb    ALL app_batch_id                277947  
1   SIMPLE  dat ref app_batch_id    app_batch_id    767 ifass.dapb.app_batch_id 1   Using where
```

**Why index on 'app_batch_id' not work when join, even force using index**

Comment: The table statistic shows that this index usage is more expensive then table scan...

Comment: If you are storing Chinese, be aware that `CHARACTER SET utf8` does not have all Chinese characters.  `utf8mb4` does.  If you are using MySQL 5.5 or 5.6, see http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes for an issue that might lead to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which runs faster?  Sometimes the "Optimizer knows best".  However, the `EXPLAINs` seem the same?

I would expect these to help significantly with performance:

```
dat:  (course_id, app_batch_id)  -- the table has nothing like this
dapb:  (app_batch_id)
```

When seeing a `JOIN`, the Optimizer usually looks at the `WHERE` clause to decide which table to start with.  But, alas, there is no index for `dat.course_id`.  SO it needs to run the query in a "brute force" way -- Scan all of one table, then reach into the other.  A strong clue of this is `ALL .. 277947` in the `EXPLAIN`.  That says that it could not benefit from any available index on `dat`.

If it had such an index, the Optimizer would start with `dat`, reach in for perhaps 1 row, not 277947, then reach into the other table using the index you already have, even without using `FORCE INDEX`.

Comment: thanks a lot, you really helped me. I saw  `ALL .. 277947`, but t found the `table` of the same line is `dapb`, so I was attracted by `dapb`.